# Amazon Cloud Drive - REST API code samples

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, drive

I am planning to use Amazon Cloud Drive to store all my files and I wish to upload and download all files using REST APIs.

All I need is I have some exe files in my computer which I need to upload to a location in Amazon Cloud and once the exe files is available in cloud, I need to download to another computer.

I dont have any apps to register (the registration part is confusing)

is there a  code snippet in c# which any one can share with me to get started.

The exe file is in C Drive and need to upload to  a folder in Cloud Drive. This is my simple requirement.

And when the exe file is available in the cloud drive, I need to download it to another computer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But is aws powershell suited for amazon cloud drive?

Comment: The reason being I am not using any EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have samples for cloud drive. You will need to map all the rest methods to c#.you can try this code but is a third party implementation https://github.com/Rambalac/AmazonCloudDriveApi

Answer (score -3):

I assume by "Cloud Drive" you mean S3? The easiest way to upload files is to use the web UI or the cli https://aws.amazon.com/cli/. However if you want to do it in code then you should use an SDK, e.g.:

- Java - https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/
- .Net - https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/

Or if you really want to roll your own you could use the S3 REST API http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html

Comment: Nope. CloudDrive != S3

https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/pricing?ref_=cd_home_navpricing